# Remember ANTLR rules/nodes in AST

Tags: antlr

I'm writing a simple query parser implemented with ANTLR, and I'd like to retrieve a tree representation of the query. For this, I'm using `options { output = AST }`. Then I parse the query and get the tree (the code is python):

```
lexer = MyQueryLexer(char_stream)
tokens = antlr3.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
parser = MyQueryParser(tokens)
q = parser.query()  # query is my root rule
# do something with q.tree
```

Now, the tree I get from my parser does not include any rule names, just tokens in a flat list. I can use rewrite rules and `^`/`!` get them into a tree structure, however they are still just tokens. For example, a part of one of the queries might be `color = 1`. That matches the following rule (simplified):

```
propcondition
: propertyname '=' value
```

That would be turned into:

```
# token type, text
5 color
20 =
8 1
```

With `'='^` I can turn it into:

```
20 =
  5 color
  8 1
```

But I'd like that fragment to remember that it was matched as a "propcondition". The closest thing I could find was introducting fake tokens with rewrite rules:

```
propcondition
: propertyname '=' value -> ^(PROPCONDITION propertyname '=' value)
// ...
```

which then gives:

```
4 PROPCONDITION
  5 color
  20 =
  8 1
```

Is this the way to go? I have a feeling I'm missing some basic function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the way to go. Note that if you create a root called `PROPCONDITION`, you can drop the `'='` sign: such a condition will  always ever have two children, right? A left-hand-side, and a right-hand-side.

```
propcondition
 : propertyname '=' value -> ^(PROPCONDITION propertyname value)
 ;
```

Creating the following tree:

[image]

And in case there are more operators, you can do:

```
propcondition
 : propertyname '=' value -> ^(PROPCONDITION ^('=' propertyname value))
 | propertyname '<' value -> ^(PROPCONDITION ^('<' propertyname value))
 | ...
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure about how I'm going to deal with the '=' yet, since there will be several operators. Either leave it in there, or create different tokens for each condition. I guess one is as good as the other.